# Ошибка Field 'us_id' doesn't have a default value?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `personal`(`name`)  VALUES ('Alex');
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'us_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Что ни делаю, вставляю в какое-либо поле данные, всегда этот баг, само поле пробовал удалить, но затем эта ошибка возникает еще на нескольких полях, не пойму в чем дело?

Comment: да, видимо это и стало причиной, пришлось немного помучиться, хорошо что это только тестовая таблица, удалил ее и создал заново с нормальными полями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что надо инициализировать все поля, которые не имеют значения по-умолчанию или задать им это значение.